# Error al enviar Array como parámetro de entrada a procedimiento en base de datos Oracle desde JAVA

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedure, excepciones, jdbc

Buen día,

Me encuentro tratando de consumir un procedimiento que tiene definidas las siguientes entradas

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PRC_REGNOTIFICACIONES (vcIdPantilla    IN VARCHAR2,
                                               vcMsisdn        IN VARCHAR2,
                                               obVariabNotif   IN OUT TYPTBL_NOTIFICACION,
                                               vcCanal         IN VARCHAR2,
                                               vcCodResp       OUT VARCHAR2,
                                               vcDescResp      OUT VARCHAR2,
                                               vcTipoUsuario   IN VARCHAR2 default '',
                                               vcEmail         IN VARCHAR2 default '') IS
```

El tipo TYPTBL_NOTIFICACION

```
create or replace TYPE TYPTBL_NOTIFICACION IS TABLE OF TYPREC_NOTIFICACION
```

El objeto TYPREC_NOTIFICACION

```
create or replace TYPE TYPREC_NOTIFICACION AS OBJECT(
 vcIdOferta      VARCHAR2(50),     
 vcDescOferta    VARCHAR2(1000),   
 nmCantIncl      NUMBER,           
 vcUndIncl       VARCHAR2(10),     
 nmValorOferta   NUMBER(16,4),    
 nmPorcConsumo   NUMBER,           
 vcOtros         VARCHAR2(3000)    
)
```

Codigo JAVA

```
//FUNCIONA PERO NO PUEDO QUEMAR LOS PARAMETROS
java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.0.0.1:8080:SID", 
"USER", "PASS");

 //FUNCIONA PARCIALMENTE HASTA EL MOMENTO DE CREAR EL ARRAY         
 java.sql.Connection conn = controladorJPA.getDataSourceRLDSUS().getConnection();

                if(conn!=null){
                     logEjb.info(loggerDTO, rutaLog, "Connexión a db correcta");
                }


                //bookStructArray[0] = struct;
                logEjb.info(loggerDTO, rutaLog, "Cantidad de notificaciones en lista: " + request.getNotificacion().size());

                Array arr = ((OracleConnection) conn).createOracleArray("TYPTBL_NOTIFICACION",
                        getNotiArray(request.getNotificacion(), conn));
                logEjb.info(loggerDTO, rutaLog, "Cantidad de notificaciones en array: " + arr.getArray().toString());



                callableStatement = (OracleCallableStatement) conn
                        .prepareCall(app.getParametro(ParametroSistema.WS_NOTIFICACIONES_PRC_REG_NOTIFICACIONES));

                callableStatement.setString(1, request.getVcIdPantilla());
                callableStatement.setString(2, request.getVcMsisdn());
                callableStatement.setArray(3, arr);
                callableStatement.setString(4, request.getCanal());
                callableStatement.registerOutParameter(5, Types.VARCHAR);
                callableStatement.registerOutParameter(6, Types.VARCHAR);
                callableStatement.setString(7, request.getVcTipoUsuario());
                callableStatement.setString(8, request.getVcEmail());

                callableStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Construcción del array de TYPREC_NOTIFICACION

```
private Struct[] getNotiArray(List<NotificacionDTO> listaNotificaciones, Connection conn) throws SQLException {
    Struct[] notiStructArray = new Struct[listaNotificaciones.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < listaNotificaciones.size(); i++) {

        Object[] obj = new Object[]{listaNotificaciones.get(i).getVcIdOferta(),
            listaNotificaciones.get(i).getVcDescOferta(),
            listaNotificaciones.get(i).getNmCantIncl(),
            listaNotificaciones.get(i).getVcUndIncl(),
            listaNotificaciones.get(i).getNmValorOferta(),
            listaNotificaciones.get(i).getNmPorcConsumo(),
            listaNotificaciones.get(i).getVcOtros()};


        Struct struct = ((OracleConnection) conn).createStruct("TYPREC_NOTIFICACION", obj);
        notiStructArray[i] = struct;
    }

    return notiStructArray;
}
```

**¿Cual es el problema?**
Como se puede observar en el codigo JAVA tengo dos conexiones una es creada con DriverManager, con esta conexión el consumo del procedimiento funciona perfectamente, pero no puedo usar esta conexión productivamente ya que se exige que se utilice un JDBC configurado en el servidor WebLogic

La segunda conexión es creada mediante un JDBC configurado en weblogic, el datasource se crea correctamente, la lista de TYPREC_NOTIFICACION se crea correctamente, pero al llegar al momento de crear el Array sobre el tipo TYPTBL_NOTIFICACIONse lanza la siguiente excepción

```
**Array arr = ((OracleConnection) conn).createOracleArray("TYPTBL_NOTIFICACION",
                        getNotiArray(request.getNotificacion(), conn));**

java.sql.SQLException: Fallo al convertir a representación interna: 
weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Struct_oracle_sql_STRUCT@1a5
```

He tratado con algunas cosas pero me confunde un poco no saber si el problema es el datasource o la estructura de datos, espero me puedan ayudar, gracias de antemano

Comment: Buenas noches Tocayo, ¿Qué version de WebLogic y de Oracle estas usando? ¿usas algún framework de acceso a datos o solo es JDBC?

Comment: Buen día Alvaro

Comment: Estoy utilizando WebLogic 12.2.1.3.0,, estoy utilizando la libreria OJDBC8 en su versión 19.3.0.0, para el acceso a datos solo configure la conexión desde el servidor y la referencio en el código, IDE Netbeans y JDK jdk1.8.0_202, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que no había necesidad de crear una arreglo de Struct con la definición del objeto de la base de datos, la conexión realiza esta conversión internamente, se soluciono devolviendo el arreglo sin ningún formato adicional.

```
   private Object[] getType(List<NotificacionDTO> listaNotificaciones) throws SQLException {

    Object[] bookStructArray = new Object[listaNotificaciones.size()];

     for (int i = 0; i < listaNotificaciones.size(); i++) {

        Object[] obj = new Object[]{listaNotificaciones.get(i).getVcIdOferta(),
            listaNotificaciones.get(i).getVcDescOferta(),
            listaNotificaciones.get(i).getNmCantIncl(),
            listaNotificaciones.get(i).getVcUndIncl(),
            listaNotificaciones.get(i).getNmValorOferta(),
            listaNotificaciones.get(i).getNmPorcConsumo(),
            listaNotificaciones.get(i).getVcOtros()};

        bookStructArray[i] = obj;
    }

 return bookStructArray;
}
```